# Override visibility in html

Tags: html, css, visibility

I try to write some css code. Unfortunately I can't change the html code
, only the style part. In my project I have the style in a css file.
Here is some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1.my_class {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="my_class" hidden>This is a heading</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Can I override the "hidden" that's written in the html code with my css code. What is already written doesn't change anything.

Comment: Should you have the hidden attribute on the element if you want to show it? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden: *The hidden global attribute is a Boolean attribute indicating that the element is not yet, or is no longer, relevant. The hidden attribute must not be used to hide content that could legitimately be shown in another presentation*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use display:block instead of visibility. Please see the below code

```css
h1.my_class {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="my_class" hidden>This is a heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h1.my_class {
    display: inline;
}
```

Try this instead of what you've written, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why the element is hidden in HTML if it's supposed to be shown with CSS anyway? Of course the HTML markup might be something that comes from another source and you have no control over it.

So if you just change you're CSS to this:

```
h1.my_class {
  display: block;
}
```

That would do it, no need to use `!important` here either. Here's a fiddle if you want to experiment with it: https://jsfiddle.net/27q7d157/

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried your ideas. I can use

```
display: block
```

or

```
display: inline
```

but I must use

```
visibility: visible
```

too.

For just a text or image just the "display" is good. But for more like a hidden span inside a hidden div I have to use also

```
visibility:visible
```